# WCF service call spawning multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, iis

We are facing an issue where WCF service breaks (intermittent (that too once in 6 months) and we are not able to replicate the scenario in any env.) and stops serving further request, creating a deadlock scenario.

We are calling multiple calls to database, other WCF services all via using async await.

We are suspecting that service is exceeding the maximum number of threads allowed.

Here is a sample I created and this is sort of creating the same behavior

Service code

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public int GetDataUsingDataContract()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = this.GetNumberAsyc().Result;
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private async Task<int> GetNumberAsyc()
    {
        return await this.GetNumber();
    }

    public Task<int> GetNumber()
    {
        Task[] tArr = new Task[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            tArr[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    Task delayTask = Task.Delay(1);
                    delayTask.Wait();
                }
                );
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tArr);

        return Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(
            () =>
            {

                Task delayTask = Task.Delay(200);
                delayTask.Wait();
                Random r = new Random();
                return r.Next();
            });
    }
}
```

We also suspected that this might be because of SynchronizationContext.

Service is hosted on IIS.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Update:

Below is a sample ASP.NET webpage hosted in IIS

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = (Test().ToString());
    }

    private int Test()
    {
        //var task = AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync();
        //var data = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        //var data = task.Result;

        var task1 = AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync();
        //var data1 = task1.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var data1 = task1.Result;

        return data1;
    }

    protected async Task<int> AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead); //.ConfigureAwait(false);

        return result.Content.Headers.ToString().Length;
    }
```

This code doesn't work and if we write the same code in WCF service and host the service in IIS, same code works well.

Is there a difference in how WCF and ASP.NET manages contexts while both are hosted in IIS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deadlock could happen if no threads finishes its work and maximum worker thread count reached in ThreadPool.

In your case, it isn't a deadlock (at least the code posted here, in real code it could be). It will take long time to complete. Just because threadpool's heuristics is waiting for threads to complete before adding new worker threads.

You can prove this by setting the MinThreads and MaxThreads of threadpool before starting your tasks.

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1000, 1000);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 1000);
```

Now the `GetDataUsingDataContract` will complete soon, as we have enough threads created upfront. Please note that **I'm not recommending this. This is purely for demonstration**. Never change the Min/Max threads unless you know what you're doing.

We can't provide a specific answer as there isn't enough information available. My advice is you'll have to leverage the `async` features. Don't block a thread unnecessarily. Use inherently asynchronous operations (which don't need any thread) as much as possible. For example: Database calls, Web requests, network access, etc [can be done purely asynchronously](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

I've talked about ThreadPool's [heuristics a little here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26141323/2530848). It can give you some idea about what's going under the covers.

Comment: So if we use async await then do we have to worry about synchronizationcontext in WCF as well...as the service is running since last few months and recently it starts breaking.