# Tasks are starting sequencial instead of parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await, task-parallel-library

I need to start tasks in parallel, but I choose to use `Task.Run` instead of `Parallel.Foreach`, so I can get some feedback when all tasks finished and enable UI controls.

```
private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cells = objectListView.CheckedObjects;
    if(cells != null)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (Cell c in cells)
        {
            Cell cell = c;
            var progressHandler = new Progress<string>(value =>
            {
                cell.Status = value;
            });
            var progress = progressHandler as IProgress<string>;

            Task t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                progress.Report("Starting...");
                int a = 123;
                for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
                {
                    a = a + i;
                    Task.Delay(500).Wait();
                }

                progress.Report("Done");
            });
            tasks.Add(t);

        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine("Done, enabld UI controls");
    }
}
```

So what I expect is that I see in UI "Starting..." almost instantly for all items. What I actually see is first 4 items are "Starting..." (I guess because all 4 CPU cores are used per thread), then each second or less new item is "Starting". I have total 37 items and it takes around 30 seconds for all items to start all tasks.

How can I make it as parallel as possible?

Comment: use a parallel foreach as you are starting one at a time..

Comment: How are you running your application when you see them run like this? Do you have VS attached?

Comment: Answer is you can't. You can't make it parallel more than the cores you have. Though you can spawn multiple threads

Comment: @SriramSakthivel he's saying he has 4 cores and wants 4 threads?

Comment: @BugFinder: then how can I await for all tasks to complete and enable UI?

Comment: looking though your code again. Are you sure it's not the progressHandler locking? i.e. the threads are running but they are waiting for the processhandler "Report". This looks like it should run in parrallel.

Comment: @Pablo just as you do now its just a different for loop

Comment: @Liam His Task isn't finishing soon. So ThreadPool will add threads with its heuristics. It will take time. It looks like his 4 cores are being used but he's wasting the thread by putting in a sleep state.

Comment: I'd kinda question why your running this in parellel at all? It seems your updating UI components and thats it. This is a very odd example and likely doesn't lend itself to parellel processing at all

Comment: If you want to understand why it takes time to create more threads - refer my [relevant answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26141323/2530848)

Comment: @Liam. I am running through VS debugger. The part of inner for loop is simulating long running CPU-bound job, which I would like to start at the same time as much as possible.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: That's why I am using `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` in order to re-use the thread. But I guess the `.Wait()` part still put the thread to sleep. Right?

Comment: @Pablo Exactly. `Wait()` call is roughly equivalent to sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make it as parallel as possible?
>
> The part of inner for loop is simulating long running CPU-bound job, which I would like to start at the same time as much as possible.

It's already as parallel as possible. Starting 37 threads that all have CPU-bound work to do will not make it go any faster, since you're apparently running it on a 4-core machine. There are 4 cores, so only 4 threads can actually run at a time. The other 33 threads are going to be waiting while 4 are running. They would only *appear* to run simultaneously.

That said, if you *really want* to start up all those thread pool threads, you can do this by calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`.

> I need to start tasks in parallel, but I choose to use Task.Run instead of Parallel.Foreach, so I can get some feedback when all tasks finished and enable UI controls.

Since you have parallel work to do, you should use `Parallel`. If you want the nice resume-on-the-UI-thread behavior of `await`, then you can use a single `await Task.Run`, something like this:

```
private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var cells = objectListView.CheckedObjects;
  if (cells == null)
    return;

  var workItems = cells.Select(c => new
  {
    Cell = c,
    Progress = new Progress<string>(value => { c.Status = value; }),
  }).ToList();

  await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(workItems, item =>
  {
    var progress = item.Progress as IProgress<string>();
    progress.Report("Starting...");
    int a = 123;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
    {
      a = a + i;
      Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    progress.Report("Done");
  }));

  Console.WriteLine("Done, enabld UI controls");
}
```

Comment: What if I would need to put logical delay(Task.Delay) inside item's job? Do I have to make async lambda? I've tried and got odd result...Console.Write is happening earlier than all tasks finished.

Comment: @Pablo: No, you shouldn't use `async` inside `Parallel`. Why would you need to delay?

Comment: In real life in each item job I need to initiate some operation(CPU-Bound, but short), then poll for feedback every second.

Comment: @Pablo: Since you have both CPU-bound and asynchronous work to do, I recommend using TPL Dataflow instead of `Parallel`.

Comment: Do you mean to create a pipeline with action blocks, one for CPU-bound job and another one for feedback? I probably need to give it a try and post a new question to make sure I am on the right track.

Comment: @Pablo: Yes, that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, it is as parallel as possible. If you have 4 cores, you can run 4 threads in parallel.

If you can do stuff while waiting for the "delay", have a look into asynchronous programming (where one thread can run multiple tasks "at once", because most of them are waiting for something).

EDIT: you can also run `Parallel.ForEach` in its own task and `await` that:

```
private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cells = objectListView.CheckedObjects;
    if(cells != null)
    {
        await Task.Run( () => Parallel.ForEach( cells, c => ... ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` gave the same result, even worse. The only thing changed is the order. What I would change in order to make `Task.Delay` to give some opportunity to suspend particular task so other tasks can make use of thread? I guess the `.Wait()` part is not letting that happen?

Comment: Well, if you make your task async and `await Task.Delay` instead of waiting, it will not wait at all. But you can only transfer this to a real world scenario if you access an async api, e.g. a wcf service. If `Task.Delay().Wait()` is a placeholder for actual (cpu-) work, you're out of luck - 4 cores will only do a certain amount of work, no matter how many threads you start. In fact, they will do less and less the more threads you start, as each thread introduces overhead.

Comment: _If_ your task do async work, you will not want to use `Parallel.ForEach`, though...

Answer (score 0):

I think it relies on your taskcreation-options.

```
TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
```

Here  you can find further informations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

But you have to know, that task uses a threadpool with a finite maximum  amount of threads. You can use **LongRunning** to signal, that this task needs a long time and should not clog your pool. I thinks it's more complex to create a long-running task, because the scheduler may create a new thread.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var demo = new Program();
            demo.SimulateClick();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void SimulateClick()
        {
            buttonStart_Click(null, null);
        }

        private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++)
            {
                var taskId = i;
                var t = Task.Factory.StartNew((() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Starting Task ({taskId})");
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < 200000; ii++)
                    {
                        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Wait();
                        var s1 = new string(' ', taskId);
                        var s2 = new string(' ', 36-taskId);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Updating Task {s1}X{s2} ({taskId})");
                    }
                    Console.Write($"Done ({taskId})");
                }),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                tasks.Add(t);
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            Console.WriteLine("Done, enabld UI controls");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This indeed gives desired result, because it spawns as many threads as I have tasks. Just wondering if I could do the same with `Task.Run` or `Parallel.ForEach`...