# Task.Run takes much time to start the task

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, performance, task

In my program i have ~40 running task, defined like:

```
private void StartTryReconnectTask() {
       TryReconnectCTKS = new CancellationTokenSource();
       TryReconnectTask = new Task(this.TryReconnect, TryReconnectCTKS.Token);
       TryReconnectTask.Start();
}
```

Inside TryReconnect() there is an infinite while loop that stops only when the task is cancelled. everything seems fine to me here.

Then i need to start a task (not infinite) on a button click:

```
private void ExecuteRepairCommand(object o) {
       Task.Run(() => {
         ...
       });
    }
```

it take ~30/40 seconds to start this new task.
if i use thread everything works correctly, the thread starts instantly. why? what's the cause?

Comment: I think it might be async thing or lack their of, I don't think it starts after 30-40 sec, thats when its done. Maybe try make ExecuteRepairCommand Async, and then await the task.

Comment: Use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` flag when creating a Task.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel wow thank you! can you post the answer so i can mark it correct?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default tasks are scheduled to ThreadPool. ThreadPool won't create new threads when you schedule lot of tasks. It will wait for sometime before creating new threads(based on some heuristics). That's why you notice a delay in starting of your tasks. [I've explained it earlier here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141046/why-thread-sleep-affects-creation-of-new-tasks).

Back to your question. If your task is long running, you should really consider using `LongRunning` flag. It will instruct the Task Scheduler to give it a new thread; so your task can run independently for a long time without affecting other tasks.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    ...
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
```